# got null from xpath expression when using xsd schema with Dom4j

Tags: xpath, xsd, dom4j

I'm trying to use dom4j with my application, and I approached a problem with parsing following XML file:

```
<menu xmlns="http://example.com/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/ my-schema.xsd">
    <content>
        <caption>aaa</caption>
        <description>vvvv</description>
    </content>
</menu>
```

I initialized dom4j parser, and now I'm trying to retrieve description node:

```
Node node = document.selectSingleNode( "/menu/content/description" );
```

(I know I could use iterators, but xpath suits me better)

I've got `null` instead of the description node.

When I tried to figure out what's wrong, I removed schema declaration from xml (so there was only plain simple `<menu>` at the beginning) and then it **worked perfectly fine**.

I rather have that XSD declaration, so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your xpath fails is that it is not namespace aware.

Try this one:

```
/*[local-name()='menu' and namespace-uri()='http://example.com/']/*[local-name()='content' and namespace-uri()='http://example.com/']/*[local-name()='description' and namespace-uri()='http://example.com/']
```

Even better, download DanSharp Xml Viewer and you can generate these paths for yourself.

http://www.bizbert.com/bizbert/2007/11/25/DanSharp+XmlViewer.aspx

Comment: I ended up using `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` but your response helped me realize that this was namespace problem, so thanks!

Comment: The noNamespaceSchemaLocation is used when you are importing types from a schema which has no namespace. This is generally bad practise as I assume the XSD you are using has a namespace. So what you really should do is keep your xmlns intact in the XML instance and rely on absolute xpath queries.